# How to build header only C++ library within Bazel workspace?

Tags: c++, bazel, xtensor

I'm working on a C++ project and I need Numpy like arrays and functionalities in C++. I found some alternatives like [xtensor](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor), [NumCpp](https://github.com/dpilger26/NumCpp) etc. These are header only libraries. The problem is I'm experimenting with Bazel for the first time so, I don't have any idea about how do I add header only library to Bazel workspace. There are some suggestions like genrule-environment, rules-foreign-cc suggested on other questions around Bazel. I've added http_archive to WORKSPACE file, but I'm not sure what to add in BUILD file.

WORKSPACE file

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

all_content = """filegroup(name = "all", srcs = glob(["**"]), visibility = ["//visibility:public"])"""

http_archive(
    name = "xtensor",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    strip_prefix = "xtensor-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor/archive/refs/heads/master.zip"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "NumCpp",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    strip_prefix = "NumCpp-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/dpilger26/NumCpp/archive/refs/heads/master.zip"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    sha256 = "c2cdcf55ffaf49366725639e45dedd449b8c3fe22b54e31625eb80ce3a240f1e",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-0.1.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/0.1.0.zip",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//:workspace_definitions.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()
```

I've tried to follow documentation, but failed every time. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no build needed for header-only libraries??

Comment: header only libraries do not require building. It is build when used (included to actual source file).

Comment: You don't build header-only libraries (as there is nothing to build). Just include the headers from the library you need in your project files.

Comment: I'm curious now. What if it wasn't header-only library? I understand that I will have to include srcs along with the hdrs. Any additional param?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple things like header-only libraries, I would write BUILD files yourself, without using rules_foreign_cc. Just write a `cc_library` with no `srcs`. Something like this:

```py
http_archive(
    name = "xtensor",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    strip_prefix = "xtensor-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor/archive/refs/heads/master.zip"],
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "xtensor",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    hdrs = glob(["xtensor/*.hpp"]),
    defines = [
        "XTENSOR_ENABLE_ASSERT",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@tbb",
    ],
)
""",
)
```

`@xtensor` will be your Bazel repository. The `build_file_content` will be used to create a `BUILD.bazel` file in it. That means your code can depend on it via `@xtensor//:xtensor`, which can be shortened to just `@xtensor`. You can also put that in a separate file (say `build/BUILD.xtensor.bazel`) and then use `build_file = "@build//:BUILD.xtensor.bazel"` instead of putting it inline in `WORKSPACE` via `build_file_content`.

rules_foreign_cc is going to generate something equivalent if you get it set up, but that seems like a lot more trouble to me than just writing it yourself. I set `defines` and `deps` based on a scan through the CMakeLists.txt, you'll want to customize based on how you want it configured.

The only other thing I see that CMakeLists doing (beyond finding dependencies and setting some `-D` flags, which translate as shown above) is generating a single file that #includes all the others. If you want to do that, I'd do something like this (in the BUILD file for `@xtensor`):

```py
genrule(
    name = "gen_single_include",
    outs = ["xtensor.hpp"],
    cmd = "\n".join([
        "cat > $@ <<'END'",
        "#ifndef XTENSOR",
        "#define XTENSOR",
    ] + ["#include \"%s\"" % h[len("xtensor/"):]
         for h in glob(["xtensor/*.hpp"])
         if h not in [
             "xtensor/xexpression_holder.hpp",
             "xtensor/xjson.hpp",
             "xtensor/xmime.hpp",
             "xtensor/xnpy.hpp",
          ]] + [
        "#endif",
        "END",
    ]),
```

I may not have gotten everything perfect here, but the idea is to build up the file using `cat` to copy stdin to it, a bash here document to feed the content in, and Python-style list comprehensions to actually build up the content.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Silverman. Following your example above I successfully added NummCpp. But with xtensor, I got the following error.

`no such package '@tbb//': The repository '@tbb' could not be resolved: Repository '@tbb' is not defined and referenced by '@xtensor'`

Comment: Yes, if you want to use tbb, you'll need to get it building. You could also just skip that part, from the CMakeLists.txt it looks optional. I added it as an example of how to add dependencies. Some options if you want to use it:

* write a BUILD file for tbb (like this answer)
* use rules_foreign_cc on it and get that working
* find a precompiled tbb and write a BUILD file for it (just put a .a file in cc_library.srcs)
* find somebody else's BUILD file for it

Comment: Thanks @Brian Silverman for the informative answer, I think I'm going to omit tbb for now.